# Can't see replies to my posts and can't log in through Android or Wap site

Tags: facebook, security, android

My Android/Wap accounts stopped working 2 days ago. I'm unable to log in even though my passwords and usernames are correct. It says:

> Does not match stored session / password may have changed by Facebook for security reasons.

Now it is playing up when I log on on my laptop/PC. My profile picture changes on its own, I can post and get notifications but can't see the replies when I click on them. My friends' accounts seem fine, just mine is affected and I'm getting no response from Facebook or forums/pages and getting concerned I've been hacked now. I'm considering deactivating my account.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned that you've been hacked and are still able to log in from your laptop, you should change your password immediately.

It is odd that you're unable to do certain things on Facebook. Someone hacking your account shouldn't break basic functionality like viewing replies. If you haven't run a virus scan recently on your machine, give that a shot as well.

Comment: I tried that, it did have a virus, got rid of it. I changed my Facebook password and it is still the same. Also no help from Facebook.